How do you package arguments in an environment variable in bash?
I have an example bash script, example.sh that looks like this:
arg1=${1:-"one"}
arg2=${2:-"two"}

echo "Arg1: ${arg1}, Arg2: ${arg2}"

if I execute the command:
example.sh "sample text"

the terminal will print:
Arg1: sample text, Arg2: two

However if I store the command in an environment variable and execute it like so:
my_var='example.sh "sample text"'
$my_var

It will print:
Arg1: "sample, Arg2: text"

The issue is that the quotes are not blocking text into discrete arguments.
My question is what is the proper way to segment arguments when commands are being saved in environment variables? I'm open to changing the way that I execute the variable so long as I can save a command in an environment variable and execute it somehow.

See BashFAQ entries 50 and 48 (in that order). The right way to store an arbitrary command in the environment is with an exported function. You can use eval "$my_var" but at your own risk, and don't ignore the quotes.

Typing $my_var expands my_var and then does word splitting. This results in the three words example.sh, "sample, and text".

As for your question on environment variables: You don't. Inside a shell process, if you want to put arguments into a variable, you would use an array, but that can't be inherited to child processes. Having said this: I don't see any environment variable in your examples either; just simple bash variables. If this is enough for you, you can indeed try to use an array.
